# How to customise the model binder to ignore missing properties on postback?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

I am using MVC3, ASP.NET 4.5, C#, Razor, SQL Server 2008+

I have to start by saying that I am using a "domain object" in my postback action.

```
        public ActionResult Edit(Order myOrder)
```

It is not a ViewModel.

Therefore the default model binder will match up all form properties and assign values to myOrder. This means that null values will be assigned for:

```
a) Properties with null values
b) Missing properties.
```

b) is the killer as one can save away to the database and suddenly find a load of values wiped out.

Currently I use a mapper, called ValueInjector, which ignores nulls to prevent this problem. However it will also prevent a) ie Properties which are newly set to null, will not save.

It would be good if the default model binder could ignore any missing property from the form. I do not really understand why it does not do this out of the box anyway. I suspect I need to create a custom model binder? I do realise the usual approach is to create ViewModel and then run these into the domain object via Automapper/ValueInjector etc., but I really struggle to understand why the model binder is messing with properties in the domain object that do not exist in the form.

So how can I get the default Model Binder to ignore missing form properties?

Many thanks for any guidance.

Comment: Wouldn't the value of the property be null if the binder ignored it anyways? What other value are you looking for the property to be if its 'missing'.

Comment: This is one of the best reasons to not use Domain models in your Views. Use View Models specific to your View.

Comment: @Anon, Thanks for reply. If it was missing, then the assignment would not happen...... I have just clicked. The object is instantiated afresh and therefore empty... So there is no way round this bar VMs. It is interesting how the scaffolding generates these postback actions using Domain models rather than scaffolding the VMs then scaffolding the actions against the VMs.

Comment: @jrummell, yes I understand. I think MS's scaffolding has not helped.

Comment: Any idea of automatic methods to create ViewModels from Domain Models(From EF) ?

Comment: ive had issues like this before, even with view models. My solution was to break normalization. Use an empty view model and post with ajax. I know its not the answer your looking for, but it is a solution.

Comment: @SamJolly It is true that the default scaffolding encourages using domain models in Views and a DbContext in the Controller. I suppose that's ok for trivial projects, but typically, you should use ViewModels in your Views and move your data access to another layer.

Comment: Check out this [article on ViewModels](http://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2009/06/30/how-we-do-mvc-view-models). (It's down right now, but it was up yesterday ...)

Comment: yes I noticed it was down.... good to know that it was up yesterday, thought the blog was pulled since it is quite old.